# Download Github pull request as unified diff

Tags: git, version-control, github, diff

How can I download the changes contained in a Github pull request as a unified diff?

Comment: Normally the PR patch link is sent to the person, who's accepting the PR.

Comment: This isn't implemented in [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) yet, but I created [a feature request](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6737196-allow-a-diff-patch-file-to-be-downloaded-from-a-me) so please add your votes to it.

Comment: cf. the the last ¶ of [_Pro Git_ §6.3.3: "Managing Pull Requests: Email Notifications"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/GitHub-Maintaining-a-Project#_email_notifications)

Answer (score 679, accepted):

To view a commit as a diff/patch file, just add `.diff` or `.patch` to the end of the URL, for example:

- https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/90
- https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/90.diff
- https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/90.patch

Comment: Great, thanks. And there is also `.patch`. Why is this not exposed in the GUI? How is one supposed to discover this?

Comment: It's not documented to keep stackoverflow in business. Honestly, that is FAQ #2

Comment: Also because `git pull` is the preferred method of downloading and applying the changes.

Comment: Ooooh, thanks, this answer is worth gold. (That blogposting too.) I wonder how anyone sane can work without that, and why it is not exposed in the crappy-enough-as-is Web UI.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very useful for porting changes from Github into SVN or whatever repo you have. They all accept diff and patch, so this is a great way to make changes more portable. Thanks!

Comment: but how to ignore prefixes? a and b coming before file paths

Comment: Judging by what these return and the the links in the docs at https://developer.github.com/v3/media/#commits-commit-comparison-and-pull-requests , the `.diff` URL gives a straight diff to the default branch based on `git-diff` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff output, and the `.patch` URL gives a concatenation of the individual commits in the PR (each relative to their parent commit) in a format suitable for e-mailing based on `git-format-patch` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch output.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary use `-p1` with `patch`.

Comment: I reached here via a google search, and few hours later, I noticed that github now shows this as a "ProTip" below each PR

Comment: Apply the PR commits to your repo in one line: `curl <patch url> | git am`

Comment: how to use it from git clone, im use `git clone https://github.com/darkk/redsocks` , want use the patched version from https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/pull/162

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore. `curl https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/90.diff -o 90.diff` results in an empty file.

Comment: To answer my own comment.. Github will redirect you, so `curl -L https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/90.diff -o 90.diff` will get the diff.

Answer (score 61):

Somewhat related, to let git download pull request 123 and patch it into `mylocalbranch` locally, run:

```
git checkout -b mylocalbranch
git pull origin pull/921/head
```

Comment: Or to get the pull request onto a new PR branch  
**`git fetch origin pull/921/head:PR`**
and then merge with your current branch, giving you a chance to review the changes 
**`git merge PR --no-commit --no-ff`**

Comment: The full documentation is at https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

Comment: This requires you to setup Git with your credentials. You cannot anonymously test a proposed change (like you could by apply a diff manually). Yet another instance of Git taking a simple workflow and making it difficult.

Answer (score 6):

To get the PR changes into your local repo in an staged but uncommitted state, so you can review:

```
git pull origin pull/123/head --no-commit
```

And to generate a patch file from that:

```
git diff --cached > pr123.diff
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188591/download-github-pull-request-as-unified-diff#comment45994967_28822607) the related solution. It answers the original question and uses `git fetch` and `FETCH_HEAD`.

```bash
git fetch origin pull/921/head
cat .git/FETCH_HEAD
# Then either of
git diff `git merge-base FETCH_HEAD HEAD`..FETCH_HEAD > diff.diff # Downloads the unified diff as asked in the original question
git merge FETCH_HEAD # Applies the diff
```