# How to download a single commit-diff from GitHub?

Tags: github, diff, patch, git-diff

I would like to get a single commit (let's call it `${SHA}`) from GitHub via the web-interface.

For example, something like:

```
$ git clone http://github.com/foo/bar
$ cd bar
$ git format-patch -o .. ${SHA}~1..${SHA}
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf bar
```

...but without having to clone the entire repository (the repo in question is large).

Obviously GitHub can display the diff of a given commit via the web interface, but how I can extract that into a (unified) diff-file (ideally, with the commit-message intact)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download Github pull request as unified diff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188591/download-github-pull-request-as-unified-diff)

Comment: @ChillarAnand: No it's not. Your link is about a pull request and not for a diff from a single commit.

Answer (score 368, accepted):

OK, found the answer myself.

Adding `.patch` (or `.diff`) to the commit-URL will give a nice patch:

```
https://github.com/foo/bar/commit/${SHA}.patch
```

Thanks to [Ten Things You Didn't Know Git And GitHub Could Do](https://owenou.com/ten-things-you-didnt-know-git-and-github-could-do)...

Comment: can we directly use this url in the `git apply` command?
like `git apply <url.diff>`

Comment: @DarshanL well that is a completely different question about the powers of the `git` cmdline tool (and super simple to try out ;-)) and unrelated to github (github would just be a provider of such a file; but any patch file served over http:// would do) - however the short answer is probably: no

Comment: Is there also an easy way to get the patch if it is done in several commits? (instead of downloading and applying several patches)

Comment: If you get `Content containing PDF or PS header bytes cannot be rendered from this domain for security reasons.` with `.patch`, try `.diff`. It worked for me.

Comment: If you have binary files in your commit or PR, use `.patch` instead of `.diff`.

Comment: Oh my god, the time wasted copy-pasting...

Comment: For `Content containing PDF`, it is now blocked using either .patch / .diff

Answer (score 12):

I found I had to add a / at the end, i.e.

```
https://github.com/foo/bar/commit/${SHA}.patch/
```

Comment: as of today, I'm unable to reproduce this: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1ffaddd029c867d134a1dde39f540dcc8c52e274.patch (without trailing slash) works fine for me (tested with firefox, cURL and wget)