# github messes up users

Tags: git, authentication, github

I have a github account, math2001, and, a day ago, I've create an other one, MHSHarriers to build a static website, maintain by the organization.

My problem is that gihub thinks that the modifications I (math2001) do are made by MHSHarriers.

But, i've checked on the log on my computer, it's saying that I've made the modification, but not on github.

Here's a test:

Repo created by math2001: https://github.com/math2001/test-delete-me/commits/master

```
C:\wamp\www\delete-md (master)
λ git log
commit d1738af44dfa007a550743e96395da54593f2097
Author: math2001 <hidden_email>
Date:   Fri Nov 11 17:33:41 2016 +1100

    edit

commit 23a8b762eb520e6ba503a861e35dae3f31185599
Author: math2001 <hidden_email>
Date:   Fri Nov 11 17:31:08 2016 +1100

    first commit
```

#### I've logged in/out, didn't do anything.

I guess you understand that it is (really) annoying. Does anyone had the same problem before?

Thanks in advance

Matt

Comment: This is an annoying github "feature" (that has nothing to do with git itself, it's purely in their web interface).  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21903805/1256452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution to my problem:

GitHub links the github account to you "account" on your machine using your **email**.

Here was my conf:

machine: email1
math2001 *github account*: email**2**
MHSHarriers *github account*: email**1**

So, github understood that MHSHarriers had to be linked with machine.

Here's the page that helped me:  [Why are my commits linked to the wrong user? - User Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/)

I hope it helps somebody!

Matt