# How to find a Pull Request start SHA if it is on the fork master branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm creating a GitHub Action which runs a check to see how a pull request affects the codebase. The check needs two inputs:

1. The repository state before the PR changes
2. The repository state after the PR changes

The 2nd input is easy: its the newest commit on the PR branch

The 1st one is a bit tricky and I'm having trouble figuring it out. It can't simply be the `master` of the main (upstream) repository, because of the potential rebase issues (new changes are already on `upstream/master` which are not in the forks' `master`). So I'm using the `merge-base` between the `master` branch and the `HEAD`.

```
git merge-base master HEAD
```

This works as expected, but the problem arises if the PR is made from the forks' `master` branch. The merge-base is the same as `HEAD`.

How to get the correct `SHA` in order to checkout the repo just before the changes made on PR. GitHub handles this situation correctly and shows only the changed files.

Comment: Do you really need both inputs? Would the diff work? If the diff of the PR could work, [that's easy to get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6188591/9210961)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tip! I'm not sure yet if this is applicable to my usecase, but it definitely opens up some possibilities in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this action *after* the PR has been merged, you should look for the merge base of the *parents* of the PR commit :

```
git merge-base HEAD^ HEAD^2
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that seems to work is to find the merge base between pull request `HEAD` and `upstream` `master`.

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/${{github.repository}}
git fetch upstream
merge_base=$(git merge-base refs/remotes/upstream/master HEAD)
git checkout $merge_base
```

This assumes that the pull request is pointed to the `master` branch.